Avoid 100% cpu when I read a FIFO file
I need to read FIFO file, because it's arriving snmp traps in a FIFO file that I need to read and process them sequentially. So I've created a while (true) loop to begin to read lines of FIFO file and process the output. Problem is machine increase cpu up 100% with the use of the script. I don't know if I insert a sleep 3s in script. Will read all lines of fifo file? Or could be that it doesn't read all lines?
I need to decrease cpu performnace of script
My code is like these:
while true
do
   if read linea; then
   initialice
   PintaInfo "$linea"
   ......

Fifo file is feeding with snmp traps
Thanks and sorry for my English!

Please show how you feed your input into your while loop.

The fifo file is feeded with snmp traps

Please edit your question and explain how you pass the input data to your while loop, not to the "FIFO file".

not optimally performant but
while true; do
    if ! read linea; then
        sleep 0.1
    else
      initialice
      PintaInfo "$linea"
    fi

should do the trick. (ideally inotifywait should be used instead of sleep, but I couldn't get inotifywait to trigger on fifo writes when testing locally
‍♂️ also tried read -t timeout to reduce cpu usage, but it didn't.)

Shouldn't read just block instead of failing when there's no data to be read? Whereas if the other side of the FIFO is closed, you'd need to reopen it -- just retrying the read with a stale descriptor will never recover.

(inotify and similar aren't expected to work here; a named fifo is just a handle, there's no actual filesystem activity associated with reads or writes to/from it).

@CharlesDuffy until the first successful read, it actually does block instead of fail. after the first successful read, it fails instead of block, causing 100%-cpu-of-1-core. dunno why (tested on Ubuntu 24.04 WSL, kernel 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 )

How did you test? In particular, is the write side open or closed when you see the read end fail? (Failing is expected after the writer closes its handle, but not before; when that happens, though, the reader needs to reopen to get a new handle, it can't just block and then read again from the handle it already has).

@CharlesDuffy tested like this https://paste.debian.net/plain/1315542

So, there you're closing the FIFO after each read. If you want to emulate a case where you have a single long-lived program doing the writes (which is how FIFOs are more properly used), it wouldn't look like that -- instead, exec 3>testfifo to open the FIFO for write, then do each echo into it with >&3 appended. Used that way, you'll see the read loop block instead of fail between them; whereas exec 3>&- will close the FIFO, after which reads will fail. But when read starts failing, you can just reopen the FIFO and get back into the state where reads block until there's a writer.

@CharlesDuffy well the test managed to reproduce OP's CPU issue, remove the sleep and the script will start using 100% cpu-of-1-core after the first successful read for some reason

@CharlesDuffy when read starts failing, you can just reopen the FIFO and get back into the state where reads block until there's a writer. that sounds like a better approach :o

Thanks to all. I feed the fifo file with external snmp traps. I’m thinking maybe I shouldn’t use FIFO file and I should use regular file?
